# replace {CTRL+A} to {TAB} or {ENTER}

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a printed barcode that contains a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for specific reasons in SAP. I want to re-use the same barcode but change the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

For now i suppress the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> with this code on keydown:

```
    If KeyCode = vbKeyA And Shift = acCtrlMask Then 'Catch Ctrl+A
    KeyCode = 0 'Suppress keypress
```

and manually press enter.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to reproduce your problem on a simple form with a field.
The key CTRL is used by access to access to some events to other buttons or controls, for this reason i put on main form this procedure:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
Debug.Print KeyAscii
End Sub
```

You can use the event KeyPress on field (control) or on main form. This case require from main form.
Then i try to pulse CTRL A and see on inmmediate window (on VBA) that the number was 1.
The solution is simple, detect this KeyAscii and simulate SENDKEYS alternative.

```
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
If KeyAscii = 1 Then
    SendKeys "{Enter}" 'or eny key that you need
End If
End Sub
```

You can find more help abaout SendKeys on: [MS Access Help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/HV080756548.aspx)

So i considered that some computers with Windows 7/8/9 and Access 2007/2010/2013 could be lock your command SendKeys by security reasons.
In those case i prefer use the direct command that need like:

```
me.controlfield.setfocus
```

Other possibility is (i use normally this last)

```
DoCmd.GoToControl ("fieldname")
```